# Disable GUID prefix in LegacyExchangeDn attribute

Tags: exchange-2013

As part of a planned migration to Exchange 2013 from a third-party e-mail system, we will be interoperating side-by-side with the existing system for some time, and want to share free/busy data between them. However, Exchange 2013 makes this difficult by prefixing the user name with a GUID in the `LegacyExchangeDn` attribute in AD. We'd like to turn this off to make managing the migration and interoperability easier on us, and the cmdlet [`Set-OrganizationConfig`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997443%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) purports to let us do precisely that.

However, when I actually try and run it:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Set-OrganizationConfig -IsGuidPrefixedLegacyDnDisabled $true
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IsGuidPrefixedLegacyDnDisabled'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-OrganizationConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-OrganizationConfig
    + PSComputerName        : exchange.domain.local
```

Technet and even the `Get-Help` cmdlet include this parameter, but the cmdlet itself doesn't seem to recognize it. Am I doing this wrong, or is this a bug? If the latter, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997443(v=exchg.150).aspx) that this parameter's signature is:

```
IsGuidPrefixedLegacyDnDisabled    Optional   System.Boolean   This parameter is reserved for internal Microsoft use.
```

With the important part being:
***This parameter is reserved for internal Microsoft use.***

So you cannot use this parameter.

Comment: Okay, no idea why my browser had refused to scroll right to show that bit to me. Not the answer I wanted to get, but thanks!